# Form action to a PHP file not in public file?

Tags: php

My folder structure is as follows:

- mysite

  - php/

    - contact.php
  - images/
  - public_html/

    - index.php
    - contact.php
    - scripts/
    - stylesheets/
  - .htaccess

I have a form in `contact.php` whose action element is to a PHP script called `contact.php` which is in the `php/` directory, which is not in the document root. The document root is `public_html/`. Is there a way around this? I don't want `contact.php` visible to users as it contains my email address, so getting it to work this way should help prevent spam.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you created PHP file outside the public dir? PHP code is hidden for users, of course. Or do you really think that anybody can see login to your DB, etc.?

Comment: How would your users be able to see your email address inside contact.php?

Comment: What you mean? first u said your contact.php is not in document root, second you dont want this is accessible by public ?

Comment: If you want to go about it that way, do an include to the full system path of the file or try and set the action to the system path of that file. Plus, as Ian stated; how can anyone see your Email address, unless you've got it echo'd somewhere.

Comment: Spamming depends on the way how secure you  have written the codes and not on visibility of a file

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii- check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780951/need-help-to-develop-ecommerce-website if you can answer this, i give you all of my rep.

Comment: Please investigate routing. That's what you'll need to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Bill the Lizard deleted the question 4 mins. ago lol Typesetting was an old trade of mine too hahaha - *A#4s3d4a#D$^&&Dsghdasdgwyad wadh&W^DE&e^#&E&Q#^e7q* Interesting ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- ahh too bad, not your day then. Muahahhahaha (cough)

Comment: @Nucleo1985 You can't win 'em all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah right. Where is the OP? not even type a comment here. Better walking Q per Q then, still 9 flags left. Hahahaaha.

Comment: @Nucleo1985 OP's gone to get us all breakfast.

Comment: @Fred-ii- awesome, i will leave simple seems like solution comment for d'OP. Suggestion: simply rename the php dir to `gahwYWgdHHAsh_A787476AdAWT656w874aGDWatadgaXXzyA` then on index.php do this `require 'gahwYWgdHHAsh_A787476AdAWT656w874aGDWatadgaXXzyA/contact.php';` i bet no public access can guessing your dir name. Case closed.

Comment: Sorry guys, I live in New Zealand so I've been asleep :D So from panther's comment, users cannot see your php code even if the file is in the public directory? Also I wasn't planning on showing my email address on the page, I was only going to have a form that the user has to fill in and then process and send the message in my hidden contact.php.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no you can't do it. bcoz you cannot post data to any file which is not accessible from `http` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put that data, like email address in your form. Put it in a config file and read that configuration when you just need to send the mail. After the post, after validate all fields, load the config.php file and use the email address on it to send.

It's the best approach in your situation.